# Confused with the notations in scala

Tags: scala, dictionary

I am confused with the "each" and "_" notation in scala. I was reading an example

```
val school = list.map(each=>((each.school,each.payment),each.amount))
          .reduceByKey(_+_)
          .map(each=>(each._1,each._2))
```

for each element in the list, it takes school,payment,amount and does a map reduce sort of thing by keeping school and payment as key.

Does this line

> .map(each=>(each._1,each._2))

interprets that once reducebykey operation is done, it is mapping back the school and amount alone to school.

PLease clarify my understanding.

Answer (score 4):

First, `each` is just a variable name - you can name it however you like:

```
.map(myTuple => (myTuple._1, myTuple._2))
```

More importantly - that last mapping actually **does nothing**. Why? Because each `reduceByKey` result has the type `(K, V)` for some types `K` and `V` - a collection of *tuples*, and when you call `(each._1, each._2)` for a 2-tuple named `each`, you just create a new *identical* tuple.

**UPDATE**:
If you're interested in a `(school, totalAmount)` result, you should take only the first part of the key (which is a tuple itself!):

```
.map(each => (each._1._1, each._2))
```

Or a nicer version using pattern matching:

```
.map { case ((school, _), amount) => (school, amount) }
```

Note that this result might contain multiple records with the same `school` value, since the key also contained the `payment` part. If a school appeared twice with different payment values in the input - this last result won't have unique `school` values.

Comment: Nice description (y)